# Quick question about Godot 4 exporting a set variable

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I am just starting out Godot and I need a little help with some platforming code written in Godot 4

How do I set a default value to this ->
`@export var speed:int: set = set_speed`

The language being used in the code is gdscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we write the setters and getters on a separate line

```
@export var speed: int:
    set = set_speed
```

And now this looks like an ordinary variable declaration, followed by some modifiers. We can put the initial value exactly where we would for a variable that didn't have custom accessors: after the type.

```
@export var speed: int = 0:
    set = set_speed
```